# Android how to fail safe?

Tags: android

Currently for my Android application there is an async task that executes a few functions and then will upload the results to the backend.

Now on some devices some of the function fails and throws exception (out of memory etc  which I saw in logcat) and then the application just stops the uploading too.

Any idea how can I implement it to be more fail safe? Meaning even if the third or fourth fails, it will still continue the uploading portion.

Does try and catch resolves this? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  try-catch block for your code which throws the exception. Therefore your only option is to catch the Exception and do something with it (or just ignore it). You could make a toast to display the error

```
try{
  //  your code which can throw exceptions
 }
catch (Exception e) {
  Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

Comment: If your app is hard failing with exceptions, you pretty much have to catch the exceptions if you want to implement a smarter failsafe. You know your situation better than us, so you are the only one who will know what to do with the exceptions once you catch them.

Comment: Also, Yup's code sample catches all exceptions. I would strongly recommend that you only catch the exceptions corresponding to the problems that you know aren't fatal so that if something goes really, really wrong, your app still fails hard and therefore won't get into a worse state.